# How to set and update the title in the toolbar by clicking menu items in the Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-mvvm, android-jetpack-datastore

I need to set the name of chosen category, below is the category object code and methods I call by clicking.
Grateful for helping.

categoryItem object:

```
@Entity(tableName = "category_table")
@Parcelize
data class CategoryItem(
    val categoryName: String,
    val categoryNumber: Int,
    val categoryShown: Boolean = false,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0
) : Parcelable {
}
```

In Menu:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_cat1 -> {
                viewModel.onChooseCategoryClick(1)
                true
            }
            R.id.action_cat2 -> {
                viewModel.onChooseCategoryClick(2)
                true
            }
```

onChooseCategoryClick() in ViewModel:

```
fun onChooseCategoryClick(chosenCategory: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
    preferencesManager.updateCategoryChosen(chosenCategory)
    // what to type here
}
```

in preferencesManager:

```
suspend fun updateCategoryChosen(categoryChosen: Int) {
    dataStore.edit { preferences ->
        preferences[PreferencesKeys.CATEGORY_CHOSEN] = categoryChosen
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `choosenCategory` value is the same as the id of one of the items on your menu items. So you can find it using `when`:

```
when(choosenCategory){
    R.id.action_cat1->
    R.id.action_cat2->
}
```